# Swift / React Native How to know split view / slide over app's position relative to the whole screen?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm making a react-native based app, and I can partially use Swift code by react-native's NativeModule feature.

My app will be used as Split view / Slide over mode in iPad, and I want to know if my app is in the left-side, right-side, or Slide-over.

I could get `width` and `height`, also `origin` (CGPoint) by this code.

```swift
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first

// Then getting X, Y like this...
window.frame.origin.x
```

Now my app has only one webview, made by `react-native-webview`.
So I guess, since the webview is the whole content of the app, and it fills app 100%, so it always returns app.

I want to know, not in `webView`'s perspective, but in `app`'s perpective, the POSITION relative to the screen.

For example, if my iPad width is 1400, and if my app is on the half right side, `x` should be `700`.
And if it is on left side, it should be `0`.

I really struggled this, but couldn't find any solution.
FYI, I drawed a diagram for this question.

[image: diagram]

As I wrote on the above, I tried `UIApplication.shared.windows.first.frame`.
But it only show the `CGPoint` of `webview`, not `app` relative to the screen.

There is no API for getting 'X' or 'LEFT' in `react-native-dimension` too.
`onLayout` also not helpful.